# Android - Testing in-app subscriptions?

Tags: android, billing, subscriptions, in-app

I'm currently trying to test in-app subscriptions using the In-app Billing Version 3 API. I have downloaded the TrivialDrive test project and successfully tested in-app purchases using static responses (android.test.purchased etc). The problem I'm facing is that static responses are only supported for testing in-app purchasing NOT in-app subscriptions. The only viable way I have found so far to test in-app subscriptions is to publish the app as beta on the developer console, assign a tester email and then download the beta apk via the opt in URL. This is a slow process as it takes a while for every iteration of the product to be published. Is there any way where in-app subscriptions can be tested in a more 'classical' way? i.e. insert breakpoints in Android Studio and see what is actually happening? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We also tried to find that out once but couldn't find a good way. What's even worse, for subscriptions there is no "try" mode. So the money is really billed to your account. I heard, on the merchant console you can give that money back but that takes a lot of time. And, once you have a subscription, you can't buy it a second time which makes testing difficult.

Comment: Hi Raul. Thanks for answering. Actually publishing the app as beta, downloading the apk via the opt-in URL and actually purchasing the subscription resulted in no billing at all. In fact I received an alert informing me that "This is a test subscription. It will recur daily. You will not be charged"

Comment: Hi Nokiaowner. Ah, great to know that. I guess, we didn't have a beta back then. For the future we know :)

Comment: @Nokiaowner Hi Nokiaowner. Do you know how to test the subscription in a fast way or do you know a tutorial that test subscription? I'm waiting as pending for days...

Answer (score 0):

about testing you don't have to upload an apk everytime to the playstore and download it, you have to do it once

then you can configure you app to signed everytime you run it on you device doing that you can see the log messages by the tag you specified

hope that helps :)